# Getting app users in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get app users in javascript sdk.
Why this is not working?

```
var q = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN '
            + '(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1');

q.wait(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }
);
```

That returns []

However that works well:

```
var q = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()');
q.wait(function(resp) {
        var l = [];
        for (var i in resp) {
            l.push(resp[i].uid2)
        }
        var fql = 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (' + l.join(',') + ') and is_app_user = 1';
        var q1 = FB.Data.query(fql);
        q1.wait(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    }
);
```

The problem with the second statement is that loads all friends into browser and it makes one more request. Why isn't the first statement working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try treating is_app_user as a boolean:
(works for me using just fql)

var q = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN '
            + '(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user');

Answer (score 1):

Try [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/). See section: Old REST API calls:

> FB.API can also be used to invoke calls to the Old REST API. For
>   example, to call links.getStats:
>
> ```
> FB.api(
>   {
>     method: 'links.getStats',
>     urls: 'facebook.com,developers.facebook.com'
>   },
>   function(response) {
>     alert(
>       'Total: ' + (response[0].total_count +
> ```
>
> response[1](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).total_count));
>         }
>       );

Above + [fql.query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) = success:)